# Manipulating CodeIgniter-parsed text

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the template parser class in CodeIgniter to give the view (MVC) a designer-friendly look. I have a series of posts that I want to display, but on the front page I only want part of a post to show (first 200 characters) followed by a ... "Read More" link.

It is outputting the posts, but seems to be ignoring the PHP substr() function bc the text comes out full-length.

Inside the model class:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('parser'); 
    $this->load->model('MPosts');
}

function index() // BASE_URL
{
    $data = array("article_posts" => $this->MPosts->get_posts());
    $this->parser->parse('VPosts', $data);
}
```

Inside the view:

```
<body>
{article_posts}
    <h2><a href="posts/post/{postID}">{title}</a></h2>
    <p><?=substr("{post}", 0, 200);?>...</p>
    <p><a href="posts/post/{postID}">Read More</a></p>
    <hr />
{/article_posts}
</body>
```

Comment: You need to get the `substr()` of the article in the `index()` for your model. Then just do `<p>{post}...</p>`

Comment: Did you mean index() for the controller? Thanks. I was hoping to avoid that, but it looks like I might have to.

Comment: Can you please change your sentence "the text comes out full-length", as the output is actually "{post}"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a MySQL query to fetch the articles you can always use `SUBSTRING(article_column_name,1,200)` to only grab the first 200 chars, basically `substr()`

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: Interesting approach. Do you have any feedback performance-wise, compared to transfering the whole data and truncating it PHP-side?

Comment: Worked, thank you :) It's kind of annoying that I have to list out all the columns, instead of the typical "SELECT * FROM...". But definitely the most elegant solution so far.

Comment: Nvm :) "SELECT *, SUBSTRING(post, 1, 200) as post....." Just figured out I can still use the *. Thanks guys.

Comment: It should be faster performance-wise to use MySQL as the data is being truncated before being passed to PHP. So instead of having to send a large amount of data to PHP it sends the minimum amount.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `parser->parse()` code:

- CI first passes your template through the `load->view()` processor, just like a regular view (so it executes PHP code inside your template),
- then it passes it through the "`{pseudovar}`-replacer".

At this point I'm sure you understood the problem: `substr()` is applied to the string `"{post}"`

I can think of these options for your case:

- do the `substr()` controller-side, probably the fastest solution to fix your issue
- remove the Parser layer and use plain ol' PHP code, which is so fine
- use a third-party über heavy full-featured template engine

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo` instead of `?=` .

People tend to leave code to `load` (model) libraries in constructors of the controller in which user-defined functions will invoke calls to user-defined functions implemented in model files.

Comment: <php echo ........ ?> doesn't work either. I suspect the PHP is being ran before CodeIgniter parses. Hence substr("{post}",0,200) just results in "{post}".

Comment: Like your idea that is very thoughtfull. Cool!